# How to Decide which Tree Traversal should be used?

Tags: algorithm, tree

In one of StackOverFlow questions, I have read that if I need to delete some folder then first I need to delete the files and sub-folders in that folder (And this is a recursive process).

It was mentioned that we need to use  Post-Order traversal technique.

Is it because that in that we need to process the parent very last, i mean after deleting the sub-folders and files then we need to delete the folder?

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you manage your folders as a tree structure, your leaf nodes are files. You want to empty out a folder before deleting. So from the root node (The folder you want to delete) traverse down to the leaf nodes (the files) and delete upwards.

This way you empty out the folders before you delete them. So if you have a folder A with a folder B which contans files c and d:

A/B/c and A/B/d you delete c and d, then B and then A.

I hope this was the answer you were looking for.

Comment: how are you relating this to the PostOrder traversal?